# Git claiming it cannot push when the origin recieves it as expected

Tags: bash, git, github, continuous-integration

I noticed that my Github actions were failing despite the fact that the actual output is fine, so I checked the logs and saw that git was throwing these errors:

```
+ git push origin master
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection timed out, errno 110
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

The problem is, the actual push ***does*** go through. Checking on Github, the exact minute the logs says the push supposedly failed, I see the successful output appearing in the repository. Why is git claiming that it is failing to push while I can see the output sitting right there in my repository? Since git throws this error, Github is thinking that my action is failing so it is emailing me about it and throwing a fit, so my monitoring software is alerting me that a critical workflow is failing. Something that may be important, I am using this repo to host binary files up to 100MB, and I have quite a few of them. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/q/1056419/158506

Comment: Unfortunately there are points during a conversation where it is literally impossible to tell that the "untimely phone hang-up" was during the goodbye handshake. When that happens, there's no way to distinguish between "concluded normally" and "terminated early". Git *could* insert its own conclusion, and if Git did that *and* the hang-up happened after that point (during the normal connection hangup), rather than Git relying on a "normal hangup" status result, Git would know that things went OK, but Git doesn't.

Comment: Even if Git *did* do that, this just moves the point at which a failure becomes mysterious. So you *might* still have the same problem. The only thing to do is to trace why the network connection itself is doing this, and that's not a Git thing, nor a GitHub thing, it's a networking thing.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you push over HTTPS, there is a request, which is the data you push, and a response, which contains a status code and a body (which, for Git requests, contains messages).  If you push the data and the remote side accepts it, but never successfully sends a response, or if that response gets interrupted by a network problem or intervening system, then Git has no way of knowing that your request succeeded.

In this case, the response indicates that the message got interrupted in the middle of reading the sideband response, which means that it's not safe to assume that the remote side did indeed finish processing it.  Git therefore did the right thing by failing here.

Note that there are some possible causes.  If you're uploading a large number of binary files that don't compress well, then Git may legitimately spend a significant amount of time unpacking those objects, and may not send a sideband packet in time to keep the connection alive.  Ideally you will not store many large binary files in a Git repository, since it's not a good use for them, but you may try SSH instead, which, with keepalives, may allow the connection to live long enough to complete.  Still, you should not use Git as a backup or archiving solution, or an artifact store, for example.

It's also possible that your connection really does have some network problem (including one caused by a proxy, non-default antivirus or firewall, or TLS middlebox), in which case you'll need to fix said problem (or uninstall or remove said software or device).  Sometimes connections just go down as well.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the answer! As this is on an official Github runner, network issues probably aren't the cause, so I guess I'll just have to split my changes up into multiple pushes to fix this problem. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Whelp, turns out that I found a fix last night and forgot about it. Adding 
         git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
fixed the problem.

Comment: As [the Git FAQ outlines](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer), that means that something on your network is broken, so my answer stands.  That option should not be necessary and should have no effect unless something is breaking your HTTP requests.